How to show C++ project tree in extension
In the best case I want show in dialog just the selected project tree (without root item for a solution and neighbor projects) with project's filters for "regular files", i.e. not for some "special" things like "references" and "External dependencies". I framed needed items in green boxes in the screenshot below:

Is there an out-of-the-box solution for that? If no, is there a solution to show at least full solution tree, where I can determine selected item type or filter the tree myself?
